# Rails: label_tag in helper method not outputting code

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to write a helper method to simplify building forms using Bootstrap Twitter. When I try and put a label_tag into the helper method nothing is output. Every other helper_tag method in the function works just not this label_tag. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

name is a symbol and text is the labels text

Helper Code

```
def bootstrap_form_text_field(name, text)
    content_tag :div, class: "control-group" do
        label_tag name, text, class: "control-label"
        content_tag :div, class: "controls" do
            text_field_tag name
        end
    end         
end
```

View Code

`<%= bootstrap_form_text_field :called_number, "Called Number" %>`

Output

`<div class="control-group"><div class="controls"><input id="called_number" name="called_number" type="text" /></div></div>`

I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p0 and rails 3.2.2 if that helps.

edit:
Seems like only the last tag helper being called is being displayed. I copied the label_tag to just below the text_field_tag and the label was the only thing being displayed.

Comment: I updated my post with the code in my view im using as well as the outputted html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
def bootstrap_form_text_field(name, text)
    content_tag :div, class: "control-group" do
        label_tag(name, text, class: "control-label") +
        content_tag(:div, class: "controls") do
            text_field_tag name
        end
    end         
end
```

I'm not sure if that + will work *correctly* like that, but it's a matter of combining the results of all of the tags if you have more than one on each level, you could even combine them in a variable and then return that variable at the end of the current scope.

Comment: The plus dosent work and I trying to add the label_tag and the content_tag below it to a variable to output after the said content_tag block is done running without much luck.

Comment: Fixed it adding each line to an array then joining them at the end but I hate the way it looks >.>